# SQL How to order by and keep expanded row by another order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My result table is this:

```
  FDate       FTime      FNo   FId FRID FRCont
2016-12-19  07:25:00    1254    A1  A1   1
2016-12-19  08:45:00    1322    A2  A1   2
2016-12-19  13:20:00    4521    B1  B1   1
2016-12-19  16:40:00    7841    B2  B1   2
2016-12-19  20:45:00    1258    B3  B1   3
2016-12-19  11:25:00    3254    C1  C1   1
2016-12-19  13:10:00    3145    C2  C1   2
2016-12-19  15:20:00    3333    C3  C1   3
2016-12-20  07:35:00    7777    C4  C1   4
2016-12-20  08:50:00    7851    D1  D1   1
2016-12-20  10:30:00    45123   D2  D1   2
```

I want order by date and time in (FCont=1 rows) 
but i do not want change relation by value in column FRID and FRCont.
looks like this:

```
   FDate     FTime      FNo    FId FRID FRCont
2016-12-19  07:25:00    1254    A1  A1   1
2016-12-19  08:45:00    1322    A2  A1   2
2016-12-19  11:25:00    3254    C1  C1   1
2016-12-19  13:10:00    3145    C2  C1   2
2016-12-19  15:20:00    3333    C3  C1   3
2016-12-20  07:35:00    7777    C4  C1   4
2016-12-19  13:20:00    4521    B1  B1   1
2016-12-19  16:40:00    7841    B2  B1   2
2016-12-19  20:45:00    1258    B3  B1   3
2016-12-20  08:50:00    7851    D1  D1   1
2016-12-20  10:30:00    45123   D2  D1   2
```

please resolve with any way in sql server query.
thanks a lot.

Comment: Your sorting logic is not clear to me.  Can you elaborate on why your result set should have this order?

Comment: This result for my transfer equipment in any city but issued in first count of route.

Comment: is the table data and desired result same , or I wanna change my glasses ?!

Comment: Can you add your script?

Comment: Please explain in detail Question was not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT FDate, FTime, FNo, FId, FRID, FRCont
FROM (
   SELECT FDate, FTime, FNo, FId, FRID, FRCont,
          MIN(FDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FRID) AS Min_Date,
          MIN(FTime) OVER (PARTITION BY FRID) AS Min_Time
   FROM mytable ) AS t
ORDER BY Min_Date, Min_Time, FRID, FDate, FTime
```

The couple `(Min_Date, Min_Time)` gives the *starting* datetime value per `FRID` slice. Using this couple we can order each slice, placing in the first place the slice having the lowest datetime value followed by the slice having the next datetime value, etc.

Comment: Copied my idea. But it's OK :D

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I saw your answer only after I had written mine. I would have deleted my post though had not been for this slight difference in the `PARTITION BY` clause of the `MIN` window function.

Comment: Thank you so much Giorgos Betsos, best regard;

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select FDate,FTime, FNo,FId,FRID,FRCont from (
    select t.*
        ,min(fdate+ftime) over (partition by frid) mn
    from t) t
order by mn, frcont;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to sort by the minimum date/time for each group:

```
select t.*
from t
order by min(date + time) over (partition by frid),
         frid,
         fid;
```

Note:  You might have to convert the date/time to `datetime` for the addition to work.